# How to insert a blank line in xml document when building with linq to xml

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

```
<root>
 <a>
    <b>aaaaa</b>
 </a> 

 <a>
    <b>aaaaa2</b>
 </a>
```

How do I get that one free line between tag `<a>` without any hacks but in the proper way?

I already tried to include

```
XComment fakeBlankCommentLine = new XComment("");
XText fakeBlankTextLine = new XText("\r\n\n");
```

but it results in `<a><b>aaaaa2</b></a>` and destroys readability. I want to keep the structure but to insert that blank line.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to do it is to insert some special (or just empty, like you did) comment, and then convert the xml to string and replace this comment with a `NewLine`.

Comment: There has to be some feasable and reasonable way to increase readability when creating xml files with linq.